# How to set audience for AuthenticationAPIClient?

Tags: android, auth0, auth0-connection

When authorizing via Android SDK AuthenticationAPIClient using passwordlessWithEmail in Credentials refresh token == null.

I read that in the [article](https://community.auth0.com/t/getting-access-token-from-api-oauth-token-returns-null-refresh-token/88102) that you need to set offline_access for api and send a link to the audience on api. But AuthenticationAPIClient doesn't have anywhere in the audience field methods.

How to set the audience parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the `offline_access` scope and `audience` wherever you are logging the user in - I'm not positive using `passwordlessWithEmail` but you'd want to leverage `withScope` and `withAudience` if using [WebAuthProvider](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.auth0.android/auth0/latest/com/auth0/android/provider/WebAuthProvider.Builder.html) (Initiates Universal Login). The audience value is just the "API identifier" in your Auth0 dashboard - In the API settings be sure you've allowed offline access. The access token you receive from the login flow can then be used in the `AuthenticationClient`, to grab profile information for [example](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-android/auth0-android-login-logout-and-user-profiles#show-the-user-s-profile).